# Whats the relationship between TDD and software design?

Tags: java, junit, tdd, software-design

I was in an interview and this question was asked, whats the best way to answer this?

I know the lifecycle of TDD is as follows

```
1- Write the test
2- Run the test (there is no implementation code, test does not pass)
3- Write just enough implementation code to make the test pass
4- Run all tests (tests pass)
5- Refactor
6- Repeat
```

Lets say I would like to create a software and follow TDD. Where should I design the software? For example, I would like to design a software to enable user registration, enabling them to access their profile and search for the products.

Based on the steps I should write a test lets say for registration, then write a code for it to pass it then try to refactor it, how about design of software?
I am a bit confused.

TDD is about making new changes to the software and testing it, how about design?

### UPDATE

Lets say I am developing an application which has following features, registration, member profile, access to search feature (only to members) to search for products, second search feature that is accessible by public and members, about us page, contact us page, product payment for both searches.

Should I start thinking about design, after reaching a complete design start writing tests and then implementation code for lets say registration part, then members profile, members search feature, about us, contact us, public search feature and at the end product payment respectively?

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-newbies-guide-to-test-driven-development--net-13835

Comment: Too broad, or too opinion-based, or both, for SO. More: [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask)

Comment: As mentioned, a bit unfit for SO. Anyways, the "refactor" part is the one where you worry about the sw architecture.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I need to know what people opinion is.

Comment: @Jack: SO isn't the place for people to list their opinions. See the link above.

Comment: @Jack SO is not an opinion forum... Really sorry.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder its to learn from each other. I am confused as TDD is all about testing and adding new features to the software but how about design?

Comment: @Jack: **I understand what you're asking.** It's just not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder where should I ask it?

Comment: @Jack: I'm not aware of an SE site where it would be on-topic (but I'm also not well-versed in the plethora of other SE sites).

Comment: Who says there can't be a design step with TDD?  For a classic contrived example, take a look at Robert Martin's walkthrough of the Bowling Game Kata.  There's an up-front design before any tests are conceived.  It's there to illustrate that design is important in thinking about how the software should behave, but it shouldn't be considered set in stone because it takes place at the point at which the *least* is known about the system.  Implementation may take a different direction, as guided by the tests.

Comment: @David thanks please give me a link to that walkthrough

Comment: @Jack: https://www.google.com/#q=bowling+game+kata

Comment: This is a great question, and probably suitable for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ .  Many people see TDD as more of a design methodology than a testing methodology.

Comment: @DavidWallace thanks I will have a look at that.

Comment: I suggest you post the code for some specific example together with the test that tries to test it. Then ask about the opinion on what to do in the test (but show your attempts as well). Otherwise, this form of the question would just lead to an endless discussion.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic the reason that I asked it is that this question has been asked by my interviewer in a job interview. She was expecting a simple short answer, I could not find any. I am wondering if someone can help. If you were asked the same question in an interview, how would you answer?

Comment: It's hard to explain just in words. Try to design and test something on your own; that's the best way to learn in my opinion. At least that's what I would answer in the interview: I would think of an example and explain when and how I design, implement, test, etc. And then your question would fit in SO standard; you would have a specific use case that your question focuses on. You can also try to post this question on programmers SE site, but I think it will be considered too broad there as well.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic Alright I added an example to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *always* think about design.  The big design different between the waterfall model and TDD (or any XDD) is waterfall uses "Big Upfront Design" where the complete design is made before any code is written and the final design set in stone.

This caused problems because later requirements changes or additional clarity after development begins that would affect the overall design was very expensive in terms of time and money to change the software.

TDD still has a design upfront, it's just not set in stone.  And hopefully since your code is written in TDD style, it is fully tested and well modularized so that any downstream design changes are cheap to make and don't cause ripple effects in other modules.

Part of the Agile Manifesto is YAGNI (you aren't going to need it) which is used to keep the design as simple as needed.  If later on it turns out you need a more complicated design, it won't be as expensive to change as it would have been if made via Waterfall.

So to summarize:

Always think about design, before, during and after each step in TDD just don't make it more complicated than it needs to be with what you currently know.

here's a blog article I found that covers this in more detail:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/09/agile-myth-6-agile-means-no-upfront-design.html